# What are the options for background task in iOS

Tags: ios, background, gps, apple-push-notifications

I need to create an app for iOS which periodically sends some data to my server (GPS location, for example).
I'm looking for a demon-like solution that the user is not really aware of...

Is it even possible? What are my options?

I have already tried to research this and came up with these options:

- As a location oriented app, Apple may approve it for running in the background.
  how hard is it to get them to approve?
  Won't the user will be able to just close the app?
- Using push notifications to trigger my app to send an update. Is that possible? Can you define a callback on the device that will be invoked when the notification arrives?

Any other ideas that I may have not think about?

And another thing - this app is sort of meant for internal use, inside a corporation, so it doesn't have to be on the App Store - if that's at all possible, or makes a difference.

Comment: If this app is only for internal use then you can join 'Enterprise Developer Program' and you'll be able to distribute it (internally) without App Store. More details here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Answer (score 3):

Well, not a direct answer. But some thoughts after reading your question.

> I'm looking for a demon-like solution that the user is not really aware of...

Well, you can't start a 3rd party application without user interaction, [except the case when app uses voip](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html). Application uses 'voip' can start at system startup without user interaction.

> Won't the user will be able to just close the app?

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3)

> *Even if you develop your app using iOS SDK 4 and later, you must still be prepared for your app to be killed without any notification.
> **The user can kill apps explicitly using the multitasking UI**. In addition, if memory becomes constrained, the system might remove apps
> from memory to make more room. Suspended apps are not notified of
> termination but if your app is currently running in the background
> state (and not suspended), the system calls the
> applicationWillTerminate: method of your app delegate. Your app cannot
> request additional background execution time from this method.*

There is no way to prevent the app from showing up in multitasking bar. If it is in multitasking bar, then user can terminate it at will.

> Well user can stop you from using Location services as well..

Well I am sure you know it, after all the research you did.. User can disable use of Location services when you try to use it for the first time. OS shows an alert to the user requesting permission and user can easly click **NO**. Well as I said, I am sure you know this.

Ok, keeping in mind the above points, I think you can do these,

**1) Core Location has the ability to do Region Monitoring.**

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3)

> *Apps can use region monitoring to be notified when the user crosses geographic boundaries. You can use this capability to generate alerts
> when the user gets close to a specific location. For example, upon
> approaching a specific dry cleaners, an app could notify the user to
> pick up any clothes that had been dropped off and are now ready. In
> iOS, regions associated with your **app are tracked at all times,
> including when your app is not running**. If a region boundary is
> crossed while an app is not running, **that app is relaunched into the
> background** to handle the event. Similarly, if the **app is suspended
> when the event occurs, it is woken up and given a short amount of time
> to handle the event**.*

See if you can somehow play with region settings to make your app get executed in background periodically. Well that is one option.

**2) Use significant change monitoring feature.**

From the same documentation..

> *The significant-change location service offers a low-power location service for devices with cellular radios. This service is available
> only in iOS 4.0 and later and can also wake up an app that is
> suspended or not running.*

I don't know how much customizable this **Significant change** value can be. But this also allows an app to wake up in background.

**3) Well you can request for standard location services in background
you can declare your app as needing background location services.**

In this case you are requesting background permission to work, you need to somehow check location after say X seconds, and send update to server. You might face some challenges: like, if you tried to access location and send request to server, OS can kill the application. GPS takes a lot of memory and I don't think background app can access internet continuesly. Not sure about it though.

One more point

> *Using push notifications to trigger my app to send an update*

But push notification will show either an alert/badge or play a sound (If my understanding is correct) when notification comes. It is not what you are after right? Also no need to use push notification just to wake up periodically, you can use Local Notification and keep the server out of it.

I think the first 2 are really your only option, since they let you open in background (as per notification).

Good Luck!!

Comment: Thanks! As I keep researching I came across Apple's Mobile Device Management (MDM). Do you think it can help me in achieving my goal? that is getting some data about the device delivered to my server?